# Conver multiple excel workbooks from a file to pdf - only unhidden sheets

Tags: excel, pdf

I am trying to find a way to convert multiple excel workbooks to pdf. I have found a vba code but I want to convert only unhidden sheets from each workbook.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:
Sub BatchOpenMultiplePSTFiles()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objWindowsFolder As Object
Dim strWindowsFolder As String

```
'Select the specific Windows folder
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objWindowsFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select a Windows folder:", 0, "")

If Not objWindowsFolder Is Nothing Then
   strWindowsFolder = objWindowsFolder.self.Path & "\"

   Call ProcessFolders(strWindowsFolder)

   'Open the windows folder
   Shell "Explorer.exe" & " " & strWindowsFolder, vbNormalFocus
```

End If
End Sub

Sub ProcessFolders(strPath As String)
Dim objFileSystem As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objExcelFile As Object
Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim strWorkbookName As String

```
Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFileSystem.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileExtension = objFileSystem.GetExtensionName(objFile)
    If LCase(strFileExtension) = "xls" Or LCase(strFileExtension) = "xlsx" Then
       Set objExcelFile = objFile
       Set objWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(objExcelFile.Path)

       strWorkbookName = Left(objWorkbook.Name, (Len(objWorkbook.Name) - Len(strFileExtension)) -1)
       objWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & strWorkbookName & ".pdf"

       objWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next

'Process all folders and subfolders
If objFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
   For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
       If ((objSubFolder.Attributes And 2) = 0) And ((objSubFolder.Attributes And 4) = 0) Then
          ProcessFolders (objSubFolder.Path)
       End If
   Next
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Why not delete all hidden sheets first then continue? Ans save, or not, the original as needed, or open a copy...

Comment: I have to open all workbooks one by one. I am trying to find a way in order to avoid opening every workbook.

Comment: When you open the workbook, you can probably remove the hidden sheets before exporting to pdf.

Comment: I have 1000excels that i have to convert to pdfs. I know how to remove hidden sheets when workbook is opened.... I am talking about vba cause I want to avoid doing that one by one.